# Use of unresolved identified 'PFFacebookUtils'

Tags: ios, parse-platform, cocoapods, pffacebookutils

Unable to import `PFFacebookUtils` in the project. Parse is working but not the ParseFacebookUtils. Below are more details, what am I missing here please?

Error:
[image]

My Bridging Header:
[image]

I am using CocoaPods and FacebookSDK.framework has been downloaded already (see screenshot below):
[image]

I know that it did get installed, CocoaPods screenshot below:
[image]